# Unreasonable not enough CPU for deployment scaling

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to understand Deployment scaling with Load Balancer. I created Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud with 6 nodes: 2 cores and 13Gb RAM each (n1-highmem-2) and launch 5 Pods and 1 Load Balancer service. Each Pod has a limit specified to 5.1Gb and 1cpu. When I tried to scale my deployment to 10 Pods I got an error that my CPU number is too low. How? I have cluster with 12 cores in total and 78Gb of RAM. Here is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
   name: production
   labels:
      name: production
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: my-service
   namespace: production
   labels:
      run: mypod
spec:
   type: LoadBalancer
   ports:
      - port: 8050
        targetPort: 8050
        protocol: TCP
        name: http
   selector:
      run: mypod
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: test
   namespace: production
spec:
   selector:
      matchLabels:
         run: mypod
   replicas: 5
   template:
      metadata:
         namespace: production
         labels:
            run: mypod
      spec:
         containers:
            - name: test
              image: my-hello-world
              ports:
              - containerPort: 8050
              resources:
                 limits:
                    cpu: "1"
                    memory: "5.1Gi"
                 requests:
                    cpu: "1"
                    memory: "500Mi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other containers may be requesting CPU from your cluster (including the `kube-system` ones).

You are requesting 1 CPU for each `test` container replica, but keep in mind that each container must be scheduled in one of the nodes (being that every single node only has 2 CPU available). That means: If a node has a single `kube-system` container that is requesting any amount of CPU, the node cannot afford more than one `test` container. E.g.:

> Node 1:
>
> - calico-node-rqcw7  -   250m
> - test-83h1d         - 1000m
> - test-kd93h         - 1000m  # <----- This one cannot be scheduled because the node already is using 1250m

Use `kubectl describe nodes` command and you should figure out what containers are being scheduled in which nodes, including their CPU requests.

Comment: Thanks for answer! That is probably it. I totally forgot that there has to be a process that manages resources